# Find SQL Objects which refer table columns that does not exists

Tags: sql-server, azure-devops, sql-server-2014, sql-server-data-tools, dacpac

We have a legacy application and its database which has more than 7000 objects including stored procedure, views, functions, synonyms and so on.

Now we are implementing **Azure DevOps**, so when i import the **dacpac** file to the database project, i could see more number of **Unresolved errors**. When i check, there are more unused stored procedures and views which are referring the table columns that is not exists now.

How could i find the objects which are referring the invalid columns and tables?

Answer (score 0):

Please check [this article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3240/finding-sql-server-objects-that-reference-invalid-objects/) to find broken stored procedure using `sp_refreshsqlmodule`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you'll be able to find everything in automated way. SSDT complains to unresolved reference not only when there is broken object, but if it's using 3-4 part names as well (cross database references), so probably solution provided by @Krzysztof won't work or will work just partly.

What's needed for you to be done:

- Find all 3-4 part objects in the code
- Add all the databases needed for this code as references
- Create synonyms for each of these objects
- Use `[$(server_var)].[$(database_var)].schema.object` syntax in your synonyms

These steps are not so hard as can look like. You can do ~90% changes in bulk, using string replace across all the files. For example, if you are using objects from another database --> DatabaseA. So in the code you'll have only limited combinations of the possible object names:

- DatabaseA..tableName
- DatabaseA.dbo.tableName
- DatabaseA.other_schema.tableName
- [Database]..tableName
- ... and so on
  If you replace all these values with `dbo.tableName` where `dbo.tableName` will be the new synonym, then it should work.

Normally this process should take 1-2 days maximum.